# Display verilog function in two's complement?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to use the display function in Verilog to print the 2's complement of a binary number.

E.g. I have the following testbench output being printed:

```
Test 1 data: input A is 0b'0011010100100100 or 0h'3524 or 13604 ;

Test 2 data: input A is 0b'1101011000001001 or 0h'd609 or 54793 ;

Test 3 data: input A is 0b'0111101100001101 or 0h'7b0d or 31501 ;
```

And I use the following code to generate that:

```
$display ("Test %0d data: input A is 0b'%16b or 0h'%4h or %d ;", counter,X,X,X);
```

But I would like the decimal `%d` of the variable to be printed in 2's complement.

So for the middle example 0xd609, the decimal should be -10743 not 54793.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have really helped to show a complete example. X needs to be declared as signed, or you can cast it to a signed type value.

```
module top;
  bit signed [15:0] X;
  bit        [15:0] Y;
  initial begin 
    X = 'hd609;
    Y = 'hd609;
    $display ("Test %0d data: input A is 0b'%16b or 0h'%4h or %d ;", 1,X,X,X);
    $display ("Test %0d data: input A is 0b'%16b or 0h'%4h or %d ;", 2,Y,Y,Y);
    $display ("Test %0d data: input A is 0b'%16b or 0h'%4h or %d ;", 3,Y,Y,$signed(Y));
  end
endmodule
```

Displays

```
Test 1 data: input A is 0b'0011010100100100 or 0h'3524 or 54793 ;

Test 2 data: input A is 0b'1101011000001001 or 0h'd609 or -10743 ;

Test 3 data: input A is 0b'0111101100001101 or 0h'7b0d or -10743 ;
```

Comment: FWIW, I get quite different results simulating the above (after changing bit to reg for Verilog vs. System Verilog) : 

Simulator is doing circuit initialization process.
Test 1 data: input A is 0b'               1101011000001001 or 0h'd609 or -10743 ;
Test 2 data: input A is 0b'               1101011000001001 or 0h'd609 or 54793 ;
Test 3 data: input A is 0b'               1101011000001001 or 0h'd609 or -10743 ;

Answer (score 0):

$display will behave as you wish if the variable is declared as signed.